# Reset auto increment sequence pl-sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, auto-increment

How can i reset auto increment primary key ?

I have a doc_id_seq and a doc_pk_trg trigger like that:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE doc_id_seq START WITH 1;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER doc_pk_trg
BEFORE INSERT ON TFIDF FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN  
 IF :NEW.doc_id IS NULL THEN    
   SELECT doc_id_seq.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.doc_id FROM DUAL;  
     END IF;
     END;
 /
```

I want to learn reset the sequence  . How can I do this ?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?  You can, as Ollie points out, use `ALTER SEQUENCE` to reset a sequence.  But it should be very rare that you care about the value of the primary key.  The only one that jumps out at me is if you're doing something like manually copying data from one environment to another (i.e. prod to dev) and you need to increase the `NEXTVAL` of the sequence in dev so that you don't generate duplicate keys.  When this question gets asked, though, people are commonly trying to avoid "gaps" in the sequence-generated values which will not work.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the ALTER SEQUENCE syntax.

Tom Kyte explains how to do exactly this here:

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1119633817597

Answer (score 2):

Simply drop and then recreate the sequence.

Comment: if it's the pk of the table, don't forget to add `START WITH "max_pk+1"` on create sequence query.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would reset it

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE reset_sequence (
   p_sequence_name   IN   VARCHAR2,
   p_new_value       IN   NUMBER
)
AS
   l_current_value     NUMBER;
   v_sequence_exists   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT 1
   INTO   v_sequence_exists
   FROM   user_sequences
   WHERE  sequence_name = p_sequence_name;

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ' || p_sequence_name || '.nextval FROM dual'
   INTO              l_current_value;

   /*Not possible to increment by 0 !*/
   IF (p_new_value - l_current_value - 1) != 0
   THEN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE    'ALTER SEQUENCE '
                        || p_sequence_name
                        || ' INCREMENT BY '
                        || (p_new_value - l_current_value - 1)
                        || ' MINVALUE 0';
   END IF;

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ' || p_sequence_name || '.nextval FROM dual'
   INTO              l_current_value;

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SEQUENCE ' || p_sequence_name || ' INCREMENT BY 1 ';
EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
   THEN
      raise_application_error (-20001, 'Sequence does not exist');
END;
```

This has the added benefit over drop & recreate of not invalidating any dependant schema objects.

Comment: if you're going to the trouble of putting it all into a stored procedure I'd add some error checking to make sure the sequence exists before trying to reset it etc. and as it's executing dynamic SQL I'd probably add some SQL Injection protection too, just in case...

Comment: I agree but some people search these answers who are newbie's and you never know what they will do... I'm sure you've seen more than enough cases where something similar has happened.

Comment: ok, have changed the procdure to validate the sequence. Will make injection impossible.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
alter table "table_name"
modify "id" generated always as identity restart start with 1;
```